# @Ajax.ActionLink not replacing partial view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to replace a div with a view using `@Ajax.actionLink` when I click on that link, but it isn't working.

Here is my link:

```
<div>
 <li>   @Ajax.ActionLink("settings","Create","Test",


new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "components" , InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace}
)  </li>
</div>
```

And my target div:

```
<div id="components">
</div>
```

I have also included these js file in the layout like that:

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/Controls/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js"></script>
```

And my action result:

```
    public PartialViewResult Create()
    {
        return PartialView("Create");
    }
```

Comment: just apply breakpoint and see whether it is hitting partialviewresult or not??

Comment: Check firebug (or the browsers default developer tools) and check the response coming back from the controller. Maybe you're getting an error.

Comment: yes it hit the partialviewresult and redirect to create view but not replacing the main div @ Kartikeya Khosla

Comment: no error coming from controller. I checked it using crome.@ heymega

Comment: Do you see the partialview data in the response body? Also make sure the components id is actually on the page by viewing the html  in your developer tools. One other thing, make sure you only have one component id. Ids should not appear more than once

Comment: yes I saw the data.The id is in the same page and it is not duplicated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Believe it or not, I had everything setup correctly, except for one thing:

> To install Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax, run the following
>   command in the Package Manager Console:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax -Version 3.2.2
```

Instructions are here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/

Comment: Awesome saved my hours of debugging and headache

Answer (score 13):

For people who installed Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax(trough nu-get or not) and want to use it through a bundle, don't forget:

- To add the library in your bundleconfig. For example:

  ```
          bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/unobtrusive").Include(
                   "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*"));
  ```
- To Render it (mine is rendered in _Layout.cshtml):

  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/unobtrusive")

I know its an old post, but can't hurt to add additional information, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

When you are writing `new AjaxOptions{ --- }`, instead write it as :

```
new AjaxOptions() { .... } and write HttpMethod also in ajaxoptions.
```

The correct usage of ajax.actionlink is:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Text", // <-- Text to display
                "Action method", // <-- Action Method Name
                "Controller Name", //  <--Controller Name
                new AjaxOptions()
                {
                 UpdateTargetId="CustomerList", // <-- DOM element ID to update
                 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, // <-- Replace the content of DOM element
                 HttpMethod = "GET" // <-- HTTP method(Post/Get)
                })
```

Comment: its not working. and i did not find any document to use like   new AjaxOptions() { .... }

Comment: AjaxOptions has a default contructor containing no arguements and can be initialised using the object initialiser even without the (). Both ways are valid.

Comment: Even I have the very same problem. It would be great if somebody can provide help with this

Answer (score 1):

If it is MVC5?
Make sure you include the correct unobtrusive ajax package
i.e.,You can install  NuGet package manager console with latest package

Install-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax

After installing the latest one,its started working for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I am not sure why this is not answered the question.Just like please don't delete the answers which is worked out for others.

Comment: You appeared to be asking the OP if they are using MVC5?